# DBD::Oracle::db prepare failed: ORA-00936: missing expression (DBD ERROR: error possibly near <*> indicator at char

Tags: sql, oracle, perl

I have 2 tables A and B. I'm taking the name value of each row of table A in the array `var1` and then put values of array `var1` in WHERE condition of a SELECT query of table B and print the result of SELECT query of table B.

Code:

```
my $sql2 = 'select name,value from A';

my $sth2 = $dbh1 ->prepare($sql2);
$sth2 ->execute();
while (my @row = $sth2 ->fetchrow_array)
{
    print join(',', @row), "\n\n";
    push(@var1, $row[0]);
}

foreach(@var1 ) {
    print "$_\n";
}

print "\n";

my $sth3 = $dbh ->prepare("select name, value from B where  name in (".join(", ",@var1).")"); -  line 99
$sth3 ->execute(@var1);

while (my @row = $sth3 ->fetchrow_array)    
{
    print join(", ", @row), "\n";
}
```

But getting error:

> DBD::Oracle::db prepare failed: ORA-00904: "5": invalid identifier
>   (DBD ERROR: error possibly near <*> indicator at char 143 in 'select
>   name,value from B where name in(1,2,3,4,<*>5)') [for Statement "select
>   name,value from  B where name in(1,2,3,4,5)"] at hello.pl line 99.
>   Can't call method "execute" on an undefined value at hello.pl line
>   102.

Comment: You aren't specifying the column that your values are to be in. That is, there should be some column name between the "where" and the "in".

Comment: @gsiems  updated the  code with column name .:-                            
  Error:                                                                                    DBD::Oracle::db prepare failed: ORA-00904: "5": invalid identifier (DBD ERROR: error possibly near <*> indicator at char 143 in 'select name,value from B where name in(1,2,3,4,<*>5)') [for Statement "select name,value from  B where name in(1,2,3,4,5)"] at hello.pl line 99.
Can't call method "execute" on an undefined value at hello.pl line 102.

Comment: >> `use strict; use warnings; use diagnostics;` <<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query you are using is incorrect

```
select name,value from A where in (1,2,3,4,5)
```

Add a column name between *Where and In*

```
select name,value from A where *column_you_checking* in (1,2,3,4,5)

my $sth3 = $dbh->prepare(select name,value from B where *column_you_checking* in(".join(",",@var1)."));   -  line 99
```

Comment: Now it is showing   DBD::Oracle::db prepare failed: ORA-00904: "5": invalid identifier (DBD ERROR: error possibly near <*> indicator at char 143 in 'select name,value from B where name in(1,2,3,4,<*>5)') [for Statement "select name,value from  B where name in(1,2,3,4,5)"] at hello.pl line 99.
Can't call method "execute" on an undefined value at hello.pl line 102.

Comment: the Error is still the same.

Comment: I think some extra characters is getting appended as you join. I read same problem in http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=753029. They are recommending to add chomp (I have no idea about perl or what does chomp does, Just trying to help you)

Comment: Missing starting/ending " (double quotes) in prepare. One at the very beginning before select and the second at the very end after the ) (closing parens) delimiting in args.

Comment: @ulix added the double quotes still the same problem.

Comment: On first loop can you try this? defined($row[0]) and push @var1,$row[0];

Comment: Also if name column is char/varchar maybe is better to quote args:  .. in ('1','2','3','4','5')